# how do i use while loop to check if a social security number entered in DDD-DD-DDDD format is valid. i tried using if and got stuck?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex4_21 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("this program checks if the social security number entered is valid");
        System.out.println("Please enter a SSN");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        boolean isSSN = true;

        if (s.length() != 11){
            isSSN = false;
        }
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)))
            isSSN = false;
        else if(s.charAt(2) != '_')
            isSSN = false;
        else if(s.charAt(5) != '_')
            isSSN = false;


        //display
        System.out.println(isSSN);

        if (isSSN == true)
            System.out.println(s + " is a valid social security number");
        else
            System.out.println(s  + " is an invalid social security number");
    }

}
```

How do I use while loop to check if a social security number entered in the proper `DDD-DD-DDDD` format?.  I tried  using if and got stuck?

Comment: I don't see a while loop. A cursory check of the code seems valid and compile-worthy.

Comment: What is the point of the while loop requirement (I assume this is a class assignment)?  Is it to allow the operator to enter one SSN after another?  Or are you expected to use a loop for validation (i.e. loop through each character and check for validity)?

Comment: I am supposed to enter a number like 232-23-5436 and the systems tells me its valid but if i run 23-43-5436 it should say SSN is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) will solve your problem. The regular expression 
`[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}` should match to anything in that format, assuming that it has to be a number. Of course, it could be over-complicating things, and if you're just checking for the hyphens in the correct places, and a string of the correct length, what you have will be fine.

```
string regex = "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}";
if(s.matches(regex))
{
    System.out.println(s + " is a valid social security number");
}else
    System.out.println(s  + " is an invalid social security number");
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for while loop and not regular expressions

Comment: I read into the question that the OP was trying multiple things and had suggested while loops as something that they were thinking about @wrongAnswer

Comment: I was trying to write the code using if but it seemed a lot of works that's why i suggested while loop

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that

```
 int i=0;
 boolean isSSN =true;
 while(i<11 && !isSSN){
    Character ch = str.charAt(i);
    i++;
    if(Character.isDigit(ch) && (i==0 || i==1 || i==2 || i==4 || i==5 || i==7 || i==8 || i==9  || i==10)) {
         continue;
    } else if (ch == '-' && (i==3 || i==6)) {
         continue;
    }
    isSSN=false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You could also do this
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
        System.out.println("Invalid SSN");
}
```